# Python Stripe SDK Authentication error (key contains at least one space)

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm trying to duplicate some subscription Plans in my Stripe account using the Python SDK, so that I can update the plan prices (plans are immutable). I can successfully list all plans, so authentication is not an issue.:

```
import stripe

stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_...'
start_id = None

while True:
    if start_id:
        resp = stripe.Plan.list(starting_after=start_id)
    else:
        resp = stripe.Plan.list()

    plans = resp['data']
    if len(plans) == 0: break
    start_id = plans[-1]['id'] 

    for plan in plans:
        new_amount = get_new_plan_amount(plan['id'], plan['name'])
        new_plan = {
            "id": "%s-v2" % plan["id"],
            "name": "%s V2" % plan["name"],
            "amount": new_amount,
            "interval": plan["interval"],
            "currency": plan["currency"],
        }
        if plan['interval_count']:
            new_plan["interval_count"] = plan['interval_count']

        if plan['metadata']:
            new_plan["metadata"] = plan['metadata']

        if plan['statement_descriptor']:
            new_plan["statement_descriptor"] = plan['statement_descriptor']

        stripe.Plan.create(new_plan) ### error
```

When I try to update a plan I get the following error:

> Stripe.error.AuthenticationError: Invalid API Key provided: "{'****': *'*********** **', '********': *'*****', '********_*****': *, '********': *'***', '******': *****, '**': *'*******-v2'}". This key contains at least one space. Please delete the spaces and try again.

I don't get it. Which field is it that contains a space? I've checked the `id` field (which it seems to be suggesting) but there are no spaces in that field.

I'm using Python 2.7 and version 2013-08-13 of the Stripe API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpack the dictionary containing your parameters when creating the plan:

```
stripe.Plan.create(**new_plan)
```

Additionally, you don't need to manage pagination parameters yourself. The Python library can do it for you using [auto-pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#auto-pagination):

```
plans = stripe.Plan.list()
for plan in plans.auto_paging_iter():
    # do something with plan
```

Comment: When you say unpack, do you mean the function is expecting a JSON string as parameter?

Comment: The `stripe.Plan.create()` method is expecting keyword arguments, not a dictionary, so you need to unpack the arguments list: https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists.